# How do I format a date on the iPhone to have this specific output?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I format a date to produce the following output on the iPhone?

```
2010-09-24 13:00:00 -0700
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean this code:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; 
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```